# Geo nodes - byte color implicit conversion

Tags: export, geometry-nodes

If you try to store data in byte color type attribute using geo nodes it seems to get implicitly converted to (my guess) linear color.

For example, 0.5 is converted to 188 instead of 128 as I'd expect.

How do I avoid that?

PS The reason to store store data in Byte color for me is that some exporting formats (for example, Alembic) accepts only Byte color as custom attribute and it seems like that only way to export some additional per face corner data.

[image]